# How to change the size of a part of the text in a label in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, text, visual-studio-2012

I want to change the size of just a part of the in a label. I can't make another label. (ex: I want the word 'Title' to be bigger then the rest e.g.: 'I am asking a question').

Any ideas how to do this? Any help would be appreciated.

P.S. I am using Visual Studio 2012 to make a Windows Store app in Visual Basic.NET code

Answer (score 1):

You can take over rendering the `Label` yourself and render the text in two passes: first the larger piece and then the rest. For this you'll have to create a custom `Label` control (by deriving from `Label`) and then handle the `Paint` event. MSDN has a simple example that shows how to do this:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.paint.aspx

Be prepared to write some relatively complicated rendering logic: you'll have to calculate the positions of the text based on the sizes of the lines of text that you render and then call `DrawString()` with the right parameters to actually do the text drawing. It's fun, though.